# Custom report for tracking webiste search within specific page

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a search page in my website: `www.example.com/?page=search`. It presents an HTML form with method="get" for searching the site so a search for "test" will result in url: `www.example.com/?page=search&q=test`
There is also pagination so I end up with the following content pages tracked in analytics:

```
www.example.com/?page=search&q=foobar&page=2
www.example.com/?page=search&q=foobar&page=3
www.example.com/?page=search&q=foobar&page=4
www.example.com/?page=search&q=test
www.example.com/?page=search&q=test&page=2
www.example.com/?page=search&q=test&page=3
etc...
```

How is it possible to get a report for the search terms of "page=search"?
Should I do it via the event tracking API or is there a configuration only way via Google Analytics? Maybe a custom report?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Google Analytics on your website it can give you the things that people are searching for. On the site configuration you fill in the "Query Parameter (required)" field with the URL parameter which comes just before the word that people are searching for. In your case it's "q".